# PHP while loop multiple conditions returning no data?

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a PHP page that is returning data from a MySQL table. I decided to add a feature that would allow the user to set the number of results they want displayed, in case there are thousands of records for example.

Here is the PHP code that displays the data:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && ($row <= $noOfResults)) {
    echo '<p class="display-date">' . $row['date'] . '</p><p class="display">' . $row['id'] . ' - ' . base64_decode( $row['packetdata']) . '</p>';  
    echo '<hr align="center" width="100%" />';
    echo $noOfResults;
}
```

I was hoping that this would only display the data up to the point that the user has selected. So if the user selects 10 results, $noOfResults is set to 10, and it will only fetch the first 10 results from the database. This is currently however only displaying a "-" and the $noOfResults variable (which is desired at this point). Is my syntax wrong or is this not the correct method of going about such a problem?

Thanks, got it working with LIMIT, didn't even think to do that.

Can someone explain why this was downvoted, just trying to learn, so as to write better questions in the future, thanks.

Comment: Use `limit` in your sql query rather than comparing with the variable value

Comment: well, when `$row = array('date' => '2014-01-01')` the condition `$row = mysql_fetch_array($result) && $row <= 10` is never true, because $row is either array or number, it cannot be both. Put an internal counter in the loop or use limit

Comment: Try bracketing like this: `while (($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) && ($row <= $noOfResults)) {`. I'm not sure `$row` will be available to the second part of the while condition otherwise. Also, `$row` will be an array, and doing `$row <= $noOfResults` seems incorrect

Comment: In this case $row is an array. You use $row as such in the next line. If you compare it with a number it will always return false. You should declare a counter variable before you start your loop and increase it each time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best way to get limited data from database is LIMIT statement in query .
i assume that your query is

```
$result= "SELECT * FROM `mytable`";
```

Just add limit statement in

```
$result= "SELECT * FROM `mytable` LIMIT '$noOfResults'";
```

then your while loop will be

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        echo '<p class="display-date">' . $row['date'] . '</p><p class="display">' . $row['id'] . ' - ' . base64_decode( $row['packetdata']) . '</p>';  
        echo '<hr align="center" width="100%" />';
        echo $noOfResults;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong `$row` will be an array. So to correct this use `mysql_num_rows()` function in php to check the number of the rows. Try the code below.

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result)<=$noOfResults){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        echo '<p class="display-date">' . $row['date'] . '</p><p class="display">' . $row['id'] . ' - ' . base64_decode( $row['packetdata']) . '</p>';  
        echo '<hr align="center" width="100%" />';
        echo $noOfResults;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: mysql_fetch_array($result) it does not returns column name as key it gives integer values as key.

Comment: @suchit mysql_fetch_array($result) will return both , numaric and assoc

Comment: @suchit `MYSQL_BOTH` is default in `mysql_fetch_array()`  please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php#frefsect1-function.mysql-fetch-array-returnvalues